# Proper way to reference a forms property that is two navigation subforms deep?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this statement that i want to execute after a button has been clicked in a pop up dialog box:

```
[Forms]![MainNavigationForm].[NavigationSubform].[Form]![SubNavigationForm].[NavigationSubform].Form![Form1].Refresh
```

I keep getting an error that Access cannot recognize SubNavigationForm and thinks I am referring to a field rather than a form.
Form1 is open and when i try and run this command

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
[Forms]![MainNavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![SubNavigationForm].Form![NavigationSubform].Form![Form1].Refresh
```

Comment: thanks, but i still get the same error i have been getting

Comment: Have in mind, that the _names_ must be the names of the subform _controls_, not the names of the subforms.